# react navigation title wrapped

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

With react navigation, **StackNavigator**, simple header title is getting wrapped. How do I display the full title? In below code, title is Personal Information. But the title does not show full on iPhone 5s device and simulator.

**Versions:**

1. "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
2. "react-native": "^0.47.2"

   static navigationOptions = {
       title: "Personal Information"
   };

[image]

Comment: You can set title section width using headerTitleStyle but it will look bad. Using the excerpted title provided by react navigation itself is a good idea

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resolved it.
Specifying the headerTitleStyle with width matching to device width solve it.

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Personal Information",
    headerBackTitle : null,
    headerTitleStyle : {width : Dimensions.get('window').width}
};
```

Comment: Good solution. Thanks

Comment: the width property is not accepted anymore in recent versions of react-navigation

Answer (score 0):

If your title changes dynamically based on what you pass to `route` as params, the title will not get truncated and will overflow. To avoid that, you can do something like this:

```
function truncate(str: string, n: number) {
  return str.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + '...' : str;
}

<YourStack.Screen
  name="MyScreen"
  component={MyScreen}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    title: truncate(route.params.yourObject.title, 15),
  })}
/>
```

`truncate` is a simple function that accepts a number, shortens the string you pass in, and adds "..." thereafter.